# specific file type upload wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

i want to add more file type extension like zip,rar and pdf but i am not able to do so because "getimagesize" only allow only image file type.

```
    define('TYPE_WHITELIST', serialize(array(
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/gif',
  'application/zip',
  'application/rar',
  'application/pdf'
      )));


     for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['agp_gallery']['name']); $i++) {
      //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['agp_gallery']['tmp_name'][$i];

               if ($tmpFilePath == "") {

               }
               else {  
          $image_data = getimagesize($tmpFilePath);
    if(!in_array($image_data['mime'], unserialize(TYPE_WHITELIST))){

        $result['error'] = 'Your image must be a jpeg, png or gif!';

      } 
    }

      }
```

Comment: Because that is a code to handle images. But you can use filesize PHP function instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: Have you set any mimetypes for pdf, zip, rar etc?

Comment: @Kees Sonnema no i didn't set any mimetypes how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess, add the following for each type of file type:

`AddType application/zip .zip`

See: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/